# Little minor parts motion exercise (Exercise 1 from chapter 4 Piston)

Tags: harmony

I’m studying some minor harmony and I’ve done this little exercise with all chords in root position
[image]

My question is: since In a minor setting you have multiple choices about triads (whether you are considering melodic/harmonic/natural minor), are you basically free to choose which triad to use (from a specific scale?)

For example in 3.4 I start with C minor triad, then I go for Eb augmented triad (considering the melodic minor ascending) and then I go for F minor considering the natural minor (having the flat sixth).

So is it possible to switch between melodic/harmonic/natural choices?

(I still have to do the 3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly switch between melodic and harmonic.  In example 3.4 you even seem to be switching between C minor and C major!  Though I suspect you've just forgotten to notate a few flats.

I like the melody line C, B♮, A♭  with its astringent augmented 2nd leap, but in the context of a harmony exercise I fear it might be considered a fault!

You realise that restricting yourself to diatonic notes, those in the various forms of the C minor scale, is a very artificial situation?  Music just doesn't DO that.  There's no 'rule' (breakable or otherwise) about staying diatonic.   Perhaps there are some about voice leading and resolution of harmonic tensions.

Comment: But it's a good place to start. One bite at a time?

Comment: You've got to know the rules first, in order to break them later.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I forgot to notate some flats! Lol, also, thank you for noticing me an augmented second leap, yes it is considered a mistake in a traditional harmony exercise, as said in Piston. Gonna fix it in a bit. Thank you very much for the feedback !