# Minor Harmony doubts

Tags: harmony, chromatic

I've tried written a little chorale in four parts using minor harmony (Bb minor).

[image]

Established that for sure I have done several harmonic errors in terms of parts motion in the sense of traditional harmony, I have some troubles understanding some degrees which I intuitively assigned to some chords that I wrote (which correspond to the highlighted parts).

Basically I started with the melody and I decided to keep it without doing any further modifications.
So I harmonized keeping in mind the chords I wanted to use for each section by completing the harmony and also choosing some inversions for smooth bass movements.

QUESTION: Is it possible to MIX the harmonic possibilities (triads at this level) given by harmonic/melodic/natural minor together freely? Because I've done that depending on the melody note.

The highlighted notes.. they are not present in the harmonic possibilities notes of Bb minor, So I considered them as chromaticisms.. And I intuitively harmonized them using diminished chords.. Is this a common behavior? And if yes, why? Also, since diminished triads I used to harmonize them are not available in Bb minor, which degrees should assign to them?

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a lot of this already [HERE](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/99390/little-minor-parts-motion-exercise-exercise-1-from-chapter-4-piston/99397#99397)

Same answer.  Yes you can freely mix all forms of the minor scale.

But you've asked some new questions too.

Yes, diminished chords are often chromatic.

You've broken your own rule by departing from B♭ minor in bar 5!

But, all 'theory' apart, have you PLAYED this?   Do you like the sounds you've written?  Do you really like the Db in the second chord of bar 5?  Do you think the voicing of bar 1 sounds good?  And quite a few similar questions.

Comment: Laurence, if you feel like a question is already answered, please vote to close it as a duplicate rather than post a link to the duplicate as an answer.

Comment: Read ALL the answer, @Dom?

Comment: Yes Ok I finally got that I can mix minor scales  but what about the notation of degrees I highlighted?

Comment: @JamesArten please ask as a separate question so others can easily find.

Comment: The rest of your answer is at best a comment by not really explaining. Please use the features of the site like closing questions as a duplicate and specifying a poster trim down parts of the question so it's easier for others to find.

Comment: Why did you close it even if I asked also new questions I didn’t get an answer yet. This was not a duplicate at all.